# Read mapped drives from user profile location NTUSER.DAT flie

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I want to get mapped network drive information from user profile server NTUSER.DAT file. Can you please let me know where can I start I did find few scripts online but they are not useful. I need to search each profile (Reg load) and get the network drives info and then unload.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$user = "admin"
$profiles = get-aduser -filter {SamAccountName -eq $user} -properties * 
$sid= $profiles.sid

$profile = " \\serverprofile\drive$\ $user\NTUSER.DAT"

Reg load "HKU\$sid" $profile

Reg export "HKU\$sid\network" "C:\temp\$user\network.reg"

[gc]::collect()
Reg unload "HKU\$sid"
```

Thanks

Comment: 1.) You need to authenticate with credentials if querying remote host, and 2.) Both hosts likely need to run `RemoteRegistry` service in order for `reg load` to succeed

Comment: @Sanny: Kindly open Powershell_ise in elevated mode and do the same. Should be fine. There should not be a space in the UNC path. Kindly check that as well if you have properly set the things.

Comment: @metablaster - 1) the profile data (NTUSER.dat) for users is on a shared location server and I have access so you mean that the RemoteRegistry service on both the Jumpbox  from where I am querying and profile server where the data is should be running? Question, If the user is logged can I still read the NTUSER.dat file in registry?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about RemoteRegistry, but if it is needed then yes, it must run on both ends. From what I remember, if the user is logged in you cannot load NTUSER.dat, instead you should use existing hive in HKU that was loaded. (you can try create a new temporary key in HKU and load there but don't be sruprised if this fails)

Comment: `the profile data (NTUSER.dat) for users is on a shared location server and I have access` Also I'm not sure if this is enough unless that drive was made in PS session, try creating temporary mapped drive with `New-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem -Credentials`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not on domain to test but following works to load hive from computer on LAN, assuming you have remoting enabled:

```
$UserName = "USERNAME"
$Domain = "COMPUTERNAME"

$Cred = Get-Credential -Message "Credentials are required to access $Domain"
$CimServer = New-CimSession -ComputerName $Domain -Credential $Cred

$User = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserAccount -CimSession $CimServer | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -eq $UserName
} | Select-Object -Property Name, SID

$UserProfile = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile -CimSession $CimServer | Where-Object {
    $_.SID -eq $User.SID
} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LocalPath

$UserProfile = Split-Path -Path $UserProfile -NoQualifier

New-PSDrive -Name Remote -PSProvider FileSystem -Credential $Cred -Root \\$Domain\C$ | Out-Null

$RegKey = "HKU\Remote-$($User.SID)"
$OldLocation = Get-Location

Set-Location Remote:\$UserProfile
reg load $RegKey NTUSER.dat

[gc]::collect()
reg unload $RegKey
Set-Location $OldLocation
Remove-PSDrive -Name Remote
```